# How to disable QR scanning steps from IOS Cardboard SDK

Tags: ios, google-cardboard

I started learning about Cardboard VR.

Download the demos and able to run.

But there is one step for **QR code scanning**. I want to disable this.

Is it possible to **disable QR scanning** and launch View Directly?

Comment: where you downloaded the `Cardboard` can you show the link

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sure https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk

Comment: which one you are worked , there are four types I seen `Panorama` , `Stars`, `TreasureHunt`, `VideoWidgetDemo`

Comment: working on Panorama